# 'sqlContext' is not defined when my function calls another function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a function all_purch_spark() that sets a Spark Context as well as SQL Context for five different tables.  The same function then successfully runs a sql query against an AWS Redshift DB. It works great. I am including the entire function below (stripped of sensitive data of course). Please forgive its length but I wanted to show it as is given the problem I am facing.

My problem is with the second function repurch_prep() and how it calls the first function all_purch_spark(). I can't figure out how to avoid errors such as this one: NameError: name 'sqlContext' is not defined

I will show the two functions and error below.

Here is the first function all_purch_spark(). Again I put the whole function here for reference. I know it is long but wasn't sure I could reduce it to a meaningful example.

```
def all_purch_spark():
    config = {
    'redshift_user': 'tester123',
    'redshift_pass': '*****************',
    'redshift_port': "5999",
    'redshift_db': 'my_database',
    'redshift_host': 'redshift.my_database.me',
    }

    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
    jars = [
    "/home/spark/SparkNotebooks/src/service/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar"
    ]
    conf = (
        SparkConf()
        .setAppName("S3 with Redshift")
        .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", ":".join(jars))
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", True)
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        .set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", True)
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3-{config.get('region')}.amazonaws.com")
        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
        .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
    )
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    ##Set Schema and table to query
    schema1 = 'production'
    schema2 = 'X4production'
    table1 = 'purchases'
    table2 = 'customers'
    table3 = 'memberships'
    table4 = 'users'  #set as users table in both schemas

    purchases_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table1}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    customers_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table2}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    memberships_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table3}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    users_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table4}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    cusers_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema2}.{table4}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()
        
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('fc_purchases').getOrCreate()

    purchases_df.createOrReplaceTempView('purchases')
    customers_df.createOrReplaceTempView('customers')
    memberships_df.createOrReplaceTempView('memberships')
    users_df.createOrReplaceTempView('users')
    cusers_df.createOrReplaceTempView('cusers')

    all_purch = spark.sql("SELECT \
    p_paid.customer_id AS p_paid_user_id \
    ,p_trial.created_at AS trial_start_date \
    ,p_paid.created_at \
    ,cu.graduation_year \
    ,lower(cu.student_year) AS student_year \
    ,lower(p_paid.description) as product \
    ,u.email \
    ,u.id AS u_user_id \
    ,cu.id AS cu_user_id \
    FROM \
    purchases AS p_paid \
    INNER JOIN purchases AS p_trial ON p_trial.customer_id = p_paid.customer_id \
    INNER JOIN customers AS c on c.id = p_paid.customer_id \
    INNER JOIN memberships AS m on m.id = c.membership_id \
    INNER JOIN users AS u on u.id = m.user_id \
    INNER JOIN cusers AS cu on cu.id = u.id \
    WHERE \
    p_trial.created_at >= '2018-03-01' \
    AND p_paid.created_at >= '2018-03-01' \
    AND u.institution_contract = false \
    AND LOWER(u.email) not like '%hotmail.me%' \
    AND LOWER(u.email) not like '%gmail.com%' \
    AND p_trial.description like '% Day Free Trial' \
    AND p_paid.status = 'paid' \
    GROUP BY \
    p_paid_user_id \
    ,trial_start_date \
    ,p_paid.created_at \
    ,u.email \
    ,cu.graduation_year \
    ,student_year \
    ,product \
    ,cu_user_id \
    ,u_user_id \
    ORDER BY p_paid_user_id") 
    all_purch.registerTempTable("all_purch_table")
   
    return all_purch
```

Here is the second function that calls the above function. It is supposed to select against the registered table views set in above function:

```
    def repurch_prep():
        all_purch_spark()
        all_repurch = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM all_purch_table WHERE p_paid_user_id IN \
        (SELECT p_paid_user_id FROM all_purch_table GROUP BY p_paid_user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) \
        ORDER BY p_paid_user_id ASC")
        return all_repurch
```

When I run repurch_prep() it throws the following exception even though the SQL Context is defined in above function. I have tried returning values above but can't figure out how to get this to work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 repurch_prep()

~/spark/SparkNotebooks/firecracker/utils_prod_db_spark.py in repurch_prep()
    735     #sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate()
    736     #sqlContext = SQLContext()
--> 737     all_repurch = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM all_purch_table WHERE p_paid_user_id IN \
    738     (SELECT p_paid_user_id FROM all_purch_table GROUP BY p_paid_user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) \
    739     ORDER BY p_paid_user_id ASC")

NameError: name 'sqlContext' is not defined
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You make the sqlContect in a function that is local.

Comment: can you elaborate? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: `def fun(): x = 10` and print it outside of the function `print(x)` that will not work cuz you defined the local variable.

Comment: So a local function would look more like this?  ```def fun():
    x = 10
    print(x)

fun()```

Comment: In your case, print will work. print x on the OUTSIDE of the function. Then there is no x and cannot print.

Comment: How would I call my first function from another function though? I can do similar things in python and pandas. I am trying to perform additional operations on the spark dataframe created by the first function.  But I cant get past the SQLContext error.

Comment: use GLOBAL variable for `sc` or use only the spark session that can be inherited from the existing one by `.getOrCreate()`.

Comment: ok thanks. I will see if I can figure out how to adapt the global and local function concepts to resolve the Context errors. I am not quite clear but will look into it. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution per @Lamanus was to place variable outside of function making them global rather than storing them in a function (as I did) and call that function from another.

```
############### SPARK REDSHIFT GLOBAL CONFIG #####################
    config = {
    'redshift_user': 'tester123',
    'redshift_pass': '*****************',
    'redshift_port': "5999",
    'redshift_db': 'my_database',
    'redshift_host': 'redshift.my_database.me',
    }

    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
    jars = [
    "/home/spark/SparkNotebooks/src/service/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar"
    ]
    conf = (
        SparkConf()
        .setAppName("S3 with Redshift")
        .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", ":".join(jars))
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", True)
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
        .set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", True)
        .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3-{config.get('region')}.amazonaws.com")
        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
        .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true")
    )
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
###############################################################


def all_purch_spark():
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    ##Set Schema and table to query
    schema1 = 'production'
    schema2 = 'X4production'
    table1 = 'purchases'
    table2 = 'customers'
    table3 = 'memberships'
    table4 = 'users'  #set as users table in both schemas

    purchases_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table1}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    customers_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table2}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    memberships_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table3}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    users_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema1}.{table4}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()

    cusers_df = sqlContext.read \
               .format("jdbc") \
               .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://{config.get('redshift_host')}:{config.get('redshift_port')}/{config.get('redshift_db')}") \
               .option("dbtable", f"{schema2}.{table4}") \
               .option("user", config.get('redshift_user')) \
               .option("password", config.get('redshift_pass')) \
               .load()
        
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('fc_purchases').getOrCreate()

    purchases_df.createOrReplaceTempView('purchases')
    customers_df.createOrReplaceTempView('customers')
    memberships_df.createOrReplaceTempView('memberships')
    users_df.createOrReplaceTempView('users')
    cusers_df.createOrReplaceTempView('cusers')

    all_purch = spark.sql("SELECT \
    p_paid.customer_id AS p_paid_user_id \
    ,p_trial.created_at AS trial_start_date \
    ,p_paid.created_at \
    ,cu.graduation_year \
    ,lower(cu.student_year) AS student_year \
    ,lower(p_paid.description) as product \
    ,u.email \
    ,u.id AS u_user_id \
    ,cu.id AS cu_user_id \
    FROM \
    purchases AS p_paid \
    INNER JOIN purchases AS p_trial ON p_trial.customer_id = p_paid.customer_id \
    INNER JOIN customers AS c on c.id = p_paid.customer_id \
    INNER JOIN memberships AS m on m.id = c.membership_id \
    INNER JOIN users AS u on u.id = m.user_id \
    INNER JOIN cusers AS cu on cu.id = u.id \
    WHERE \
    p_trial.created_at >= '2018-03-01' \
    AND p_paid.created_at >= '2018-03-01' \
    AND u.institution_contract = false \
    AND LOWER(u.email) not like '%hotmail.me%' \
    AND LOWER(u.email) not like '%gmail.com%' \
    AND p_trial.description like '% Day Free Trial' \
    AND p_paid.status = 'paid' \
    GROUP BY \
    p_paid_user_id \
    ,trial_start_date \
    ,p_paid.created_at \
    ,u.email \
    ,cu.graduation_year \
    ,student_year \
    ,product \
    ,cu_user_id \
    ,u_user_id \
    ORDER BY p_paid_user_id") 
    all_purch.registerTempTable("all_purch_table")
   
    return all_purch
```